# How to Open Gmail app from link / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular

How should we open an Gmail app from hyper link

this opens whatsapp `<a href="https://wa.me/">whats app</a>`

`<a href="mailto:user@gmail.com">mail to</a>` is opening compose with default email client.

I tried with `<a href="googlegmail://">Open Gmail</a>` but nothing happens

But i am looking something to open Gmail/Yahoo app to check latest email.

Answer (score 2):

To open the Gmail app from a hyperlink in JavaScript, you can use the `intent://` URI scheme.

```js
<!-- Link to open Gmail on Android -->
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=googlegmail;package=com.google.android.gm;end">Open Gmail (Android)</a>

<!-- Link to open Yahoo on Android -->
<a href="mailto:user@yahoo.com">Open Yahoo Mail (Android)</a>

<!-- Link to open Gmail on iOS or fallback to Gmail website -->
<a href="googlegmail:///">Open Gmail (iOS)</a>

<!-- Link to open Yahoo Mail on iOS -->
<a href="mailto:user@yahoo.com">Open Yahoo Mail (iOS)</a>
```

Now I just assume you want for both Android and iOS devices. So Android devices will attempt to open the Gmail app using the `intent://` URI scheme.

iOS devices will try to open the Gmail app using the `googlegmail://` URI scheme, and if the app is not installed, it will fallback to opening the Gmail website.

And then it matters what the user has set as their default email client.

And you will never achieve to access the app to see the latest without the app start with "new email".

Comment: This is opening my google play and asking to click on Open to gmail , is there any thing that it will open directly ?

Comment: Have you set Gmail as your default email choice? I'm not sure I don't think so just because due to security and privacy reasons. The user must manually open the app on their device

Comment: Yes. I have Gmail as default app.

Comment: do we have any option to open default email app of the user device ?